# How do I get action bar to have both main and top action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

According to http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars I can have my action bar split into three locations. For my case I want the first two locations to always be visible: **Main action bar** and **Top bar**. But never the **Bottom bar**. How might I do that? Presently I can only get the **Main action bar** to show. I basically want the design of the Google Play app.

Basically I have copied and pasted and studied from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not set `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in your `manifest` you will not get third part. **Action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview.** and I recommend you do not use that. I think Google play is using  [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic)

and at the end if you insist on using actionBar tabs you can do like:

```
 final ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        String[] mTabNames = tabNames;

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabNames.length; i++) {

            ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
            tab1.setText(tabNames[i]);
            tab1.setTabListener(this);
            actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        }
```

and for your tab listener you can add below code to your activity.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
```

and do not forget `implements ActionBar.TabListener` !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the design of Google Play App can use this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

for further reference you can also see the tutorial here
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs

Answer (score 1):

As navigation tabs are going to be [deprecated in Android L](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/aanbpbAcUKW), you should consider adding tabs by using the support library's [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) or [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) (which was specifically designed to mimic the design of Google Play.